# Workflow module missing content type mapping

Tags: workflows

I don't see a tab or area to add a content type to a work flow. The documentation does not match what I am seeing. The tabs I see at the top are:

```
Primary tabs
  Edit
  States
  Transitions(active tab)
  Labels
  Permission summary
```

Where should I look to find the mapping area?

Answer (score 0):

The recent versions of workflow module comes with `workflow_field` and `workflow_node` modules. If you want to use `workflow_field`, a new feature, then you have to create a workflow field in your content type and it can also be used in any entity. But if you to use it the old way then enable `workflow_node` module and you can assign the content type to the workflow, but it can only be used for nodes.